# nginx configuration rafter replacing apache2

Tags: nginx

I was running apache2 on my laptop as a web server.Then i decided moving to nginx.

-Installed nginx - php (fastcgi - fpm) without removing apache

-configured the /etc/nginx/site-enabled/default with the next rules

```
root /var/www;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Typenig localhost from the browser it responds with 403 forbidden

Typing 127.0.0.1:9000  This webpage is not available

12.0.0.1               forbidden

I see its a permissions issue but i run chmod 777 var/www 
and apache2 when running display websites

So what's wrong with my configuration or what am i missing?

Comment: You should configure an error logfile as this may help you to debug things: `error_log /var/log/nginx/your.site.com/error.log warn;`. Instead of `warn` you can use `debug` to get the full load of messages.

Comment: Whats the OS flavor?  Can you check `/var/log/nginx/` also check the `php-fpm` logs.

Comment: The error.log file shows that for typing localhost :  
    [error] 5231#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"  
for typing localhost/website_folder :  
[error] 5231#0: *2 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"  
[error] 5231#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

If the above is the only content of your default file, than I’m wondering why nginx is even starting. You have to create a server block:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

Always check your configuration with `nginx -t` before (re-)starting.

Comment: nginx -t    
      nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()             "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)   
2013/06/19 12:30:15 [warn] 3549#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2013/06/19 12:30:15 [emerg] 3549#0: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Check permissions of `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and always execute all nginx related command either with `su` or as root user.